# Outlook 2010 context menu for attached files lacking "print" option

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, context-menu

Yo stackers =)

My coworker likes to right-click on PDF attachments and send them directly to the printer.

Her new computer runs Windows 7 OS with Outlook 2010 mail client.

I cannot find any options to turn this feature on :)

Comment: I have a *Quick Print* option for attached `.pdf` documents in emails. Is that what you're referring to?

Comment: Yes I don't have that option. I have a "Show in Acrobat Reader"-kind of option (but in Danish since it is the local language)